# rqt_tf_tree error

Tags: ros, tf2, tf-tree, ros-indigo, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I have installed the rqt_tf_tree. while running the command `rosrun rqt_tf_tree rqt_tf_tree` and getting the following terminal.

```
PluginHandlerDirect._restore_settings() plugin "rqt_tf_tree/RosTfTree#0" raised an exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/qt_gui/plugin_handler_direct.py", line 116, in _restore_settings
    self._plugin.restore_settings(plugin_settings_plugin, instance_settings_plugin)
  File "/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rqt_tf_tree/tf_tree.py", line 129, in restore_settings
    self._refresh_tf_graph()
  File "/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rqt_tf_tree/tf_tree.py", line 138, in _refresh_tf_graph
    self._update_graph_view(self._generate_dotcode())
  File "/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rqt_tf_tree/tf_tree.py", line 147, in _generate_dotcode
    force_refresh=force_refresh)
  File "/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rqt_tf_tree/dotcode_tf.py", line 97, in generate_dotcode
    self.graph = self.generate(data, timer.now().to_sec())
  File "/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rqt_tf_tree/dotcode_tf.py", line 137, in generate
    root,
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'root' referenced before assignment
```

I run with superuser also but the same error. can anybody help?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/292659/rqt_tf_tree-error/) by [simbha](https://answers.ros.org/users/29493/simbha/) on ROS Answers with karma: 241 on 2018-05-30

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-05-30**:\

> I run with superuser also but the same error.

Just a note: there is no need to try running this with elevated privileges. That won't influence this sort of problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Cool!!.
I have solved the issue. Actually, I was giving static transform in the launch file, which was conflicting with the exact transform. Removing the static transform from the launch file solved the issue

---

Originally posted by [simbha](https://answers.ros.org/users/29493/simbha/) with karma: 241 on 2018-05-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3